# Heap Dumps are getting generated and the error is "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" "native memory exhausted". How to disable those Heap Dumps

Tags: heap-dump, openj9

We are getting Heap dumps with the error "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" "native memory exhausted" in "Open J9" JVM.
Can somebody suggest how to disable these Heap Dumps

Tried -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory  -Xms4096m      -Xmx10240m.
Need to know how to disable these dumps

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting heap dumps **because** you're running out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

Using `-Xdump:heap:none` should disable all heap dumps. If you want heap dumps on other events, you can add more `-Xdump:heap:`... options after that. See more details at https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/xdump/.